# login_required decorator make a GET before POST. Then the Post has no 'next' in request

Tags: flask, flask-login

I use this code in login view:

```
def login():

    form = LoginForm()
    print("before submit request is ", request)

    if form.validate_on_submit():    
        # Some code was deleted for short
        return  redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.index'))

    return render_template('accounts/login.html', form=form)
```

When I click a link which view is :

```
@login_required
def index(count, page):
     pass
```

I get debug output is :

```
('before submit request is ', <Request 'http://192.168.1.8:9000/accounts/login?next=%2Fperson' [GET]>)  
('before submit request is ', <Request 'http://192.168.1.8:9000/accounts/login' [POST]>)**
```

So  **login_required** first make **GET** request with a **next** field. Then a **POST** without a **next** field. So it can't redict to  my click.

What can I do?

#### update add my login template

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            {{ wtf.quick_form(form, action="/accounts/login") }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: From that debug output you cannot be sure if `next` is present in the POST data or not.

Comment: I am not sure. I print  using my answer. It indeed always have `next` in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I success solve it by change the template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">

        <form
            action="{{ url_for('accounts.login', next=request.args.get('next')) }}"
            method="POST" 
            class="form" 
            role="form">

            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens='only') }}

            {% for field in form %}
                {% if not bootstrap_is_hidden_field(field) %}
                {{ wtf.form_field(field,
                        form_type="basic",
                        horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 10),
                        button_map={}) }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

But, I am not sure is this a best answer?